# jQUery ajax code alerts an empty string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I send an ajax request when the user fills the email input, here is the code:

```
_email.blur(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url : base_path("user/register/ajax/email"),
                    type: "POST",
                    data: ({ email : _email.val() , }),
                    success: function(message)
                    {
                        alert(message); 
                    },
                });
               }); // end of email blur
```

Then the php returns a string on success, and one on failure (CodeIgniter Controller)

```
if($param == "email")
            {
                $this->form_validation->set_rules("email", "required | email");
                $this->form_validation->set_rules("email", "is_unique[users.email]");
                if($this->form_validation->run !== FALSE)
                {
                    echo (json_encode("thanks"));   
                }
                else
                {
                    echo (json_encode("Ranks"));    
                }
            }
```

**PROBLEM:** it seems ajax request is successful, but the message it alerts is not appropriate since it alerts an empty string.

Comment: What is `$param`? I guess it does not evaluate to `"email"`, if the output is empty.

Comment: Have you tried checking what $param is when calling the controller?

Comment: Is "thanks" valid JSON ? Shouldn't it be [some stuff] or {some stuff} ?

Comment: I have checked it without including json and it was the same, $param is a segment of url which equals "email".

Comment: Still, if that if branch doesn't execute, then PHP is going to output an empty string with an HTTP 200, which your AJAX call is then going to alert.  I'd investigate there first.

Answer (score 0):

i'd look at this:

```
json_encode("thanks")
```

I havent coded any PHP for a long time but shouldnt json_encode be for encoding associative arrays? eg

```
json_encode(array("message" => "thanks"))
```

Answer (score 0):

as you are using json_encode you could try this after the if else statement

```
exit(json_encode($respond));
return $this->output->set_output(json_encode($respond));
```

where $respond is the message you want to display.

Answer (score 0):

```
    _email.blur(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        url : base_path("user/register/ajax/email"),
                        type: "POST",
                        data: ({ email : _email.val() , }),
                        success: function(message)
                        {
                            alert(message); 
                        }
                    });
                   });


if($param == "email")
            {
                $this->form_validation->set_rules("email", "required | email");
                $this->form_validation->set_rules("email", "is_unique[users.email]");
                if($this->form_validation->run !== FALSE)
                {
                    echo "thanks";   
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "Ranks";    
                }
                exit;
            }
```

For resonse in json you should use data type like:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
});
```

Comment: If you want response in json then data type of ajax should be 'json'.

Comment: Before alert data in js data should be parsed using JSON.parse(message). (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Answer (score 0):

php code:

```
json_encode(array("content" => "thanks"));
```

js code:

```
success: function(message)
                    {
                        alert(message.content); 
                    }
```